# MatLab - Loop through X and Y to calculate Z

Tags: matlab

I am trying to loop through some logspaces to calculate Z values and create a contour plot. But I am stuck. How can I create the contour plot now I have my Z values? And how can I set my Z variable? My calculations for Z are based on images and I cannot do it in an other way.

```
X = logspace(-10,0,10);
Y = logspace(-10,0,10);
for x = X
    for y = Y
        % here should some magic happen... but you have to assign real positive integers as indices for z
        z(x, y) = 1; % some other heavy calculation
    end
end

% what should I do here?
contourf(x, y, z); % does not work unfortunately
```

Comment: Not that you would probably want to compute thing as a function of `X` and `Y`. For instance, you could just say `Z = X.^3-2*log(Y);` and compute `Z` elementwise from `X` and `Y`.

Comment: In other words: if possible, design your function such that it runs on matrices! Then you don't need the for loop and can just write `Z = f(X,Y)`, which is usually faster.

Comment: True that, but it becomes more complex when computing average correlation of 20 image pairs for different X and Y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
X = logspace(-10,0,10);
Y = logspace(-10,0,10);
for x = 1:numel(X)
    for y = 1:numel(Y)
        %// Note the reversed y,x - this is because the x-axis in an image / chart is usually mapped to the horizontal axis which is the columns whereas matrix representations would have dimension one as the rows. Hence you need to put x in dimension 2 and y in dimension 1
        z(y,x) = 1; %// i.e. z(y,x) = f(X(x), Y(y))
    end
end

contourf(X, Y, z);
```

Comment: Yes, it almost does :)! It is now giving the following complaint: The size of X must match the size of Z or the number of columns
of Z. Where $X$ has $numel(X)=2$, $Y$ has $numel(Y)=3$ and $Z$ has 3 columns and 2 rows.

Comment: @Kevin try my edit - I just switched `x` and `y` around when assigning to `z`

Comment: Thanks! It works :)! Now I have to wait 30 minutes for the results :).

Comment: A double loop takes a lot of time, you might want to try to vectorise this problem, or, if already optimally implemented, going parallel. Especially when having to wait 30 minutes.